Is there a way to create a protobuf repeated field with fixed size, and separatly set some of values by index with c++?
Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language.
I have a data structure, that includes fields listed below:
Header header                       
time stamp 
float64[4] prism_angle              
uint8[1206] data                    

I need to convert this structure in protobuf message, and this is the result:
message MsgPacket {
    optional Header header = 1;
    optional double stamp = 2;
    repeated double prism_angle = 3;
    repeated uint8 data = 4; 
}

The problem is that in one packet there is a fixed data size of 1206, and it is required to change values via index in a few specific circumstances. How to achieve such result?
I'm using proto2.
Appreciate any help.

I would simply check the length in my code, and reject it if it's not what I want. There's also a bytes type that's similar to string, which might be easier to deal with in this case since it translates to std::string as well.
